# Typescript get type from class that is undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to be able to determine the type of something before I use it.  So i have the value "y" and "N" that i want to convert to boolean when the field is boolean.
I dont want to hardcode the field, so i am looping through the object to set the value.  Is there any way to inspect the type before you set it?

Here is an example of an object:

```
export class test {
    id: string;
    foo: number;
    bar: boolean;
}
```

I have tried doing this code however it returns undefined until the value has been set ... however by that point I could have overwritten what the object should be (like it would be string now)

```
typeof test['bar']
```

Comment: You can't. While those properties exist in the typescript context, when you compile to js those properties are gone. The only way to keep them is by assigning a value to them or you can use the [metadata decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#metadata) to save that for you

Comment: @NitzanTomer, do you think adding a set bar into the class and having it do the logic would resolve what i need?
something like this:

    class test {
        bar: boolean;
        set bar (bar:boolean | string) {
            this.bar = (typeof bar === "string") ? ((bar === "Y") ? true : false) : bar;
        }

Comment: Yes, that is the idea behind `setters`. But you won't be able to call your member `bar` and name the method the same way. Usually, people then use `_bar` in this case. Also, next time edit your question and add the code there and only reply with saying that the question was updated. It's hard to read code in comments

Answer (score -2):

> I want to be able to determine the type of something before I use it

For classes you can use `instanceof`. Example

```
class Foo{}
const foo = new Foo(); 
console.log(foo instanceof Foo); // TRUE
```

## More

TypeScript doesn't have special runtime type information beyond what JavaScript has. That said TypeScript understands usage of JavaScript metadata checks like `instanceof` and `typeof`.